# Всплывающие блоки по клику через js

Tags: javascript, html, css, классы

Добрый вечер, коллеги!
Прошу помочь человеку, недавно начавшему изучать `js`.
Есть задача - некая боковая навигация, состоящая из списка со ссылками, при клике на ссылку должен появляться блок со связанным по теме контентом, при клике на другую ссылку, блок исчезает, появляется другой. Задачу нужно решить посредством использования чистого `js`. Подскажите в какую сторону копать, какие темы смотреть?

На сколько я понимаю со своим уровнем логического мышления на данный момент - нужно задать переменную и собрать в нее массив со всеми совпадениями по классу ссылки и в другую переменную совпадения с классом блока (через `getElementByClassName`), после чего сравнить их и при совпадении индекса (полагаю через `if`) задать блоку класс c видимостью, а у других удалить. Единственное пока не понимаю как в эту схему приклеить клик по конкретной ссылке.

Спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужно познакомиться с браузерными событиями. Вы можете отслеживать нажатие на элемент и дальше уже изменять свойства у других элементов. Прочитайте например тут https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Comment: Можете воспользоваться запросом "tabs in pure js" или "вкладки на javascript" в поисковике - вам выдаст множество примеров с подробным пояснением и готовых решений как на русскому, так и на английском

Answer (score 2):

ну вот с нахрапу как то так
тут логика какая...
 если при клике класс у `div` такой же как у `li` то убираем класс `hide` иначе присваиваем оный.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.click');

ul.addEventListener('click', el => {
  switch (el.target.tagName) {
    case 'LI':
      const len = divs.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (divs[i].classList.contains(el.target.className)) {
          divs[i].classList.remove('hide');
        } else {
          divs[i].classList.add('hide');
        }
      }
      break
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item1">item 1</li>
  <li class="item2">item 2</li>
  <li class="item3">item 3</li>
  <li class="item4">item 4</li>
  <li class="item5">item 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="main">
  <div class="click item1 hide">item 1</div>
  <div class="click item2 hide">item 2</div>
  <div class="click item3 hide">item 3</div>
  <div class="click item4 hide">item 4</div>
  <div class="click item5 hide">item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

По последнему вопросу о кликах - пример из lear.javascript не много изменен. А в остальном Вам уже ответил Cheg

```js
  function handler1() {
    //Делаете что-то с любым элементом
    alert('Спасибо ещё раз!');    
  };

  function handler2() {
    //Делаете что-то с любым элементом
    alert('Спасибо ещё раз!');
  }
  
  let redBtn = document.querySelector('.red-btn'); // получаем кнопку
  
  redBtn.addEventListener("click", handler1); // вешаем обработчик, при клике вызывается функция handler1
  elem.addEventListener("click", handler2); //  вешаем обработчик на input, при клике вызывается функция handler2
```

```html
<input id="elem" type="button" value="Нажми меня"/>

<button type="button" class="red-btn">Нажми</button>
```

Comment: И каких же образом данный код относится к поставленной в вопросе задаче?

Comment: @Cheg Последняя строка в вопросе: "Единственное пока не понимаю как в эту схему приклеить клик по конкретной ссылке." Но заминусовали правильно, человек другое имел ввиду

Comment: Тут дело даже не в минусах) Думаю, ответ будет намного качественнее, если он будет содержать хотя бы примерно решение с более или менее понятным пояснением. Такие ответы как раз и будут полезны остальным посетителям.

Comment: @Cheg Согласен. Спасибо за разъяснение. Я тут новенький, так что намотал на ус ))